# Why can you import a package *after* using its content in a function?

Tags: matlab, import, package

I'm on MATLAB R2014b and have a question that I will illustrate with the following example.

MWE can be made as follows or [download it as a .zip file here](https://erikieperikie.stackstorage.com/index.php/s/QuWnbhJeHL17rEw).

Create a package folder `+test` on your path with four function files in it:

```
+test
    a.m
    b.m
    c.m
    d.m
```

Content of `a.m`:

```
function a
disp 'Hello World!'
```

Content of `b.m`:

```
function b
a
```

If you run `b` from the command line, you will have to import the `test` package first (`import test.*`) or run `test.b`.

Running `b` will result in an error, since the scope of function `b` doesn't contain function `a`. We must import it before it can be used. For this I've created `c.m`:

```
function c
import test.*
a
```

Now running `c` works fine.

Now my question. If I change `c.m` to (saved in `d.m`):

```
function d
a
import test.*
```

I.e. the import command is issued *after* the call to package function `a`. Running `d` still works just fine, as if the position of the import command in `d.m` does not matter. The import appears to have occurred before the call to function `a`, which in `d.m` happens on the line before the import.

Why does this happen. Is this the intended behaviour and what are its uses? How and in what order does MATLAB read a `.m` file and process it? And more off-topic, but in general: how is importing packages handled in different languages compared to MATLAB, does the order of commands matter?

My preemptive conclusion based on the comments: It is probably best practice to only use the import function at or near the beginning of MATLAB code. This makes clearly visible the imported content is available throughout the entire element (e.g. function). It also prevents the incorrect assumption that before the import, the content is not yet available or refers to a different thing with the same name.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I'm sure it's not my misunderstanding. I have been very careful with the imported packages before editing `b.m`. I used `clear all`, `clear classes` and `clear import` before any steps I took, but judging from the documentation on `import`, this is not necessary: every function has its own workspace and import list (you can check this with `L = import`). Even if the main MATLAB workspace has a package imported, it will not be passed to any function you call from the command line. Note: scripts work in the workspace they are called in, so they inherit the import list from there.

Comment: I've edited the question. Now `b.m` is not changed, instead two files `c.m` and `d.m` have been added. I also added the MWE as .zip file for those who want to try it themselves. Function `d.m` now is the one with the interesting behaviour.

Comment: I understand your problem now. I don't have an answer though, but the import command seems to be preprocessed before anything else is called. The doc says ***Do not use import in conditional statements inside a function. MATLAB preprocesses the import statement before evaluating the variables in the conditional statements.***.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I think that should be an answer.

Comment: @Bernhard it's a little weak for an answer.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Good find. This supports the theory of the import function being processed before executing the ‘regular’ code. By the way, how are imports usually handled in other languages, since I have no importing experience in other languages? I've added this to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MATLAB performs static code analysis prior to evaluating a function in order to determine the variables/functions used by that function. Evaluation of the `import` statements is part of this static code analysis. This is by design because if you `import` a package and then use it's functions, MATLAB needs to know this during the static code analysis. As a result, regardless of *where* you put the `import` statement within your function, it will have the same effect as if it were at the beginning of the function.

You can easily test this by looking at the *output* of `import` which will list all of the current imported packages.

**`+test/a.m`**

```
function a(x)
    disp(import)
    import test.*
end

test.a()

%   test.*
```

This is why [the documentation states](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/import.html) to *not* put an `import` statement within a conditional.

> Do not use `import` in conditional statements inside a function. MATLAB preprocesses the `import` statement before evaluating the variables in the conditional statements.

```
function a(x)
    disp(import)
    if x
        import test.*
    else
        import othertest.*
    end
end

test.a()

%   test.*
%   othertest.*
```

The only way to avoid this behavior is to allow the static code analyzer to determine (without a doubt) that an `import` statement won't be executed. We can do this by having our conditional statement be simply a logical value.

```
function a()
    disp(import)
    if true
        import test.*
    else
        import othertest.*
    end
end

test.a()

%   test.*
```

As far as importing compared to other languages, it really depends on the language. In Python for example, you must place the `import` *before* accessing the module contents. In my experience, this is the typical case but I'm sure there are many exceptions. Every language is going to be different.

Comment: Just to add that in Java you normally add the imports in beginning of each file. Java is not exactly like Matlab though. in c++ the keyword `using` does the same thing, and is normally added in the beginning of each file (after the **#include**s). Tread very carefully when using these imports. In case there are multiple functions with the same name. In that case it is better to use the dot notation. I would recommend to use import in the beginning of each scope and only import unique functions.